# How to select just one div under specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform search on the div with class "searchable" but I'm not sure how I should select it. I tried something like the code before but it didn't work.

```
                $('#SEARCH').change(function () {
                //if (e.which == 13) {
                    var txt = $('#SEARCH').val();
                    $('.divin').each(function(){
                       if($(this + ' > .searchable').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1){
                           $(this).hide();
                       }
                    });
                //}
            });
```

**($(this + ' > .searchable')** is incorrect

HTML:

```
<li id="listItem_156" class="divin">
<div style="width:30px;">
    <a href="#?w=800" rel="popup_name" id="156" class="poplight">
        <img height="16" style="cursor:move;" width="16" src="img/arrow.png" border="0"  />
    </a>
</div>
<div style="width:220px;" class="searchable">
    <a href="action=MemberDetails&item=156" class="body">Mike Frank </a> 
</div>
<div style="width:110px;">
    0 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not directly  this

```
 $('.divin .searchable').each(function(){
```

hence

```
 $('#SEARCH').change(function () {
                //if (e.which == 13) {
                    var txt = $('#SEARCH').val();
                    $('.divin .searchable').each(function(){
                       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1){
                           $(this).parent().hide();
                       }
                    });
                //}
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery.find`

```
if($(this).find(' >.searchable').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1){
      $(this).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways :

first with `.find()`:

```
$('.divin').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('> .searchable').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1){
        $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

second with a given context like this:

```
$('.divin').each(function(){
   if('> .searchable', this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) == -1){
        $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQLS9/)

```
    $('#SEARCH').change(function () {
        var txt = $('#SEARCH').val();
        $('.divin .searchable').show().filter(function () {
              return $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) === -1
        }).hide();

    });
```